# Flask_sqlalchemy many to many query

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created the following models:

```py
tag_post = db.Table('tag_post',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), primary_key=True))

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(180))
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tag_post, backref=db.backref('posts_associated', lazy="dynamic"))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
```

How can I query all the posts tagged with a tag, by using the tag.id?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a join.

You want all posts that meet a condition. The query should therefore start with the table `Post`.

```
Post.query
```

Then you bind the table posts with your join table using the two columns that should fit. In this case the column `post_id` in the `tag_post` table and `id` in the `Post` table. Since you use your association table directly, the columns used are referenced using the name via the attribute `c`.

```
Post.query\
    .join(tag_post, tag_post.c.post_id == Post.id)
```

Then you filter the second column of your join table based on your condition.

```
tag_id = 1
Post.query\
    .join(tag_post, tag_post.c.post_id == Post.id)\
    .filter(tag_post.c.tag_id == tag_id)
```

Since you want all posts and not just one, close the request with `all()`.

```
tag_id = 1
tagged_posts = Post.query\
    .join(tag_post, tag_post.c.post_id == Post.id)\
    .filter(tag_post.c.tag_id == tag_id)\
    .all()
```

The following is a detailed query with the same result, which also includes the third table.

```
tag_id = 1
tagged_posts = Post.query\
    .join(tag_post, tag_post.c.post_id == Post.id)\
    .join(Tag, tag_post.c.tag_id == Tag.id)\
    .filter(Tag.id == tag_id)\
    .all()
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. The query works perfectly and the logic behind it is easily understandable. Answer accepted